# How to compile multiple .cpp files in vim

Tags: c++, vim

I am a newish programmer trying to figure out how to compile two separate `.cpp` files and `.h` file. From my google search so far, I have found that I need to enter something like:

```
gcc -o myprogram file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

Can someone expand on this?

Comment: Vim is an editor, not a compiler. Search for _compiling multiple source files gcc_. You probably want g++ instead.

Comment: So it would just be the same command with g++? I have been struggling with this for quite a while sadly.

Comment: You should rather use something to help you with it - GNU Make, CMake, Meson...
It's rather inconvenient and restrictive to use a single `g++` invocation for this.

Answer (score 3):

For a temporary session (or in a possibly local `.vimrc` file), you can specify the builtin `makeprg` variable (see also `:help makeprg`)

```
set makeprg=g++\ -o\ myprogram\ file1.cpp\ file2.cpp
```

and invoke the compilation via `:make`. This will open up the quickfix window if you had any compilation errors or warnings, which can be handy.

Note, however, that this is nothing but a temporary hack for quick trial-and-error cycles. When these two files are meant to be something more serious, choose a build system and configure it accordingly. Then, adjust the `makeprg` variable again to invoke e.g. `make` (which is the default anyway), `ninja`, `scons` (in case you hate yourself) or whatever tool you chose.